# How to treat boolean?

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

I've received a boolean from a query, and I want to check if the boolean's value is greater than zero. Is it possible to modify the approach used when handling resources to check a boolean's value? (See; example of resource handling below:)

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Any help appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP would interpret as a string, you can simply cast it as `(bool)`

```
return (bool)(mysql_result($query, 0));
```

Non-zero values will cast as `TRUE`.  Note that you should only do this if the return values are 0 or 1. Negative values will cast as `TRUE`.

```
var_dump((bool)"1");
// bool(true)
var_dump((bool)"0");
// bool(false)
var_dump((bool)-2);
// bool(true)
```

Comment: Can I add the true : false to your code sample, as in the example I gave?

Comment: nothing wrong with your answer but data received by php from mysql, is always a string, including integers, floats, bools

Comment: @NorS it is unnecessary to add the ternary operation.  Casting via `(bool)` does the same thing.

Comment: @NorS it will be useless because you will reassign the same boolean value that already have

Comment: I still get this error: Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Func\subscribe.func.php on line 20

Comment: @NorS Ohhhhhh.  That's a totally different problem - you aren't receiving a boolean value from the database, but `$query` is `FALSE` because your query failed!  Look here for many many related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given

Answer (score 0):

Just do `return mysql_result($query, 0) == 1;`

Don't do something like `return $a_boolean_value ? true : false;`.

Answer (score 0):

> I've received a boolean from a query

that is not true. you can't get boolean from the query but merely a *string.*

> I want to check if the boolean's value is greater than zero.

1. booleans cannot be measured in that way. boolean can be either true or false. or, it you like it - zero or non-zero. not "greater" but just "not".
2. 'greater than' operator in PHP is `>`. so, you can use it in your expression instead of `equal` operator(`==` one)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was confused about the boolean type.